# Kinect v 2.0 Keeps disconnecting

Tags: windows, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2

So I am using the Kinect 2.0 for Windows, with the Kinect SDK library. Now, for some reason, the Kinect will just randomly restart in the middle of my program.

From what I've seen it may just be an issue with USB 3.0, but none of the fixes I have used so far seem to work, and the USB Port works perfectly with any of my other hardware I am using.

So, are there any settings I can easily change (Besides in the BIOS, as I will need to use this fix on a number of laptops) that will fix this problem?
I have already disabled USB selective suspend, and have tried numerous USB ports.

Comment: If you are very certain it is not the USB port that is the problem. Do check if your kinect code have any code that closes the Kinect Sensor or does not receive any form of frame at that point of time. to check this you can run the debugger line by line to see which part cause the sensor to be offed

Comment: @bingcheng45 It's not just while running my code though, I am pretty sure there is some issue with the way Kinects in general work with Windows that cause this issue, especially since I have recreated this issue on numerous laptops, with numerous Kinects, using both my program and windows programs meant for the Kinect (Like the 3D scanner)

Comment: can you show us the error message you are getting?

Comment: @bingcheng45 There is no error message, it's just the Kinect shutting down, as if I pulled it out of the USB... So I'll just get no Kinect connected type messages from these programs.
And after a second or two the Kinect is turned on again and the messages go away.

The problem is with my code is then the user to recalibrate themselves into the program every time the Kinect restarts, which is inconvenient to say the least.

Comment: I have not gotten such issues with the kinect before other than my friend's USB 3 port was loose. Could it, maybe be the kinect was damaged?

Comment: @bingcheng45 Then I have 3 damaged Kinects, and/or 4 damaged laptops, which is unlikely...

Comment: sorry I'm just trying to pin point the problem.
Does the problem occur even on sample Kinect code provided by Microsoft? if not then we may need to examine the code, as it could highly be the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148801/discussion-between-flotolk-and-bingcheng45).

Comment: Use Kinect studio and run it for a while and check is it still getting disconnected or not, If it still get disconnected, try the same with another computer. In the second computer still it happens, there is a defect in the hardware. And check whether the fan is working or not.With kinect studio, it should run without any errors unless any hardware problem including usb connectivity. As I remember XBOX connect comes without a separate power cable, which is can't use with normal computers without a external power source.

Comment: @ShanilFernando all three Kinects will disconnect after a few minutes. It's only for a few seconds, but that's all it takes for the Kinect to lose all of its calibration information.

Comment: I think you can read this thread if you haven't yet. [Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2af9bf2-8d52-4406-98ef-0ae21ab25016/kinect-v2-freezing-then-restarting-repeatedly-within-a-few-seconds-even-with-samples?forum=kinectv2sdk) . I have never faced this problem, so it is hard for me to pin point the issue.

Comment: @ShanilFernando thanks for the link, I fixed my disconnecting problem with my Kinect v2 sensors, I disabled the microphone array a while back, and having it disabled was causing the disconnecting problem, after enabling it again the Kinect started to work again without disconnections.